# checking dimension failes on onload image at testing with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, onload

I have a task to make check a dimension of an image after user input is changed.
Here is the simplified code that does the job in the browser.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Avatar = () => {
  
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const checkDimension = async (result) => {
    const image = new Image();
  
    const promiseImg = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('Started');
      image.onload = () => {
        
        if (image.height <= 100 && image.width <= 100) {
          resolve(true);
        }else{
          resolve(false);
        }
      
        image.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
      };
    });

    image.src = result;
    
    console.log('finished with result', await promiseImg);
    return promiseImg ;
  };

  const handleImageLoad = async ({ target }) => {
    const image = target.files[0];

    const reader = new FileReader();

    const promiseReader = new Promise(resolve => {
      reader.onload = async ({ target: { result } }) => {
        if (await checkDimension(result)) {
          resolve(true);
        }else{
          resolve(false);
        }
      };
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(image);

    await promiseReader ? setErrorMessage('Good dimension') : setErrorMessage('Wrong dimension');
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type='file'
        onChange={handleImageLoad}
        accept='image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png'
        data-testid='imageInput'
      />
      <p>{errorMessage}</p>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Avatar;
```

But when I test it in JEST RTL it can't complete image.onload despite that I'm awaiting the promise resolve.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

import Avatar from './avatar';

describe('Avatar test dimensions', () => {
  let uploader;
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<Avatar />);
    uploader = screen.getByTestId('imageInput');
  });

  it('should give error for wrong dimension of real image file with size 102x1px', async ()=>{
    

    const file = new File(
      ['iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGYAAAABCAYAAAAsLtuAAAAAEklEQVR42mNkYPhfzzAKBh0AAGClAYCUny1uAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'], 
      'image102x1.png', 
      { type: 'image/png' }
    );

    fireEvent.change(uploader, {target: { files: [file] } });
      
    expect(await screen.findByText('Wrong dimension')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('should pass real image less than equal 100x100',async ()=>{
    const file = new File(['iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAEklEQVR42mP8/5/hPwMQMMIYAELqBf31meVMAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'], 'image2x2.png', { type: 'image/png' });

    fireEvent.change(uploader, {target: { files: [file] } });

    expect(await screen.findByText('Good dimension')).toBeInTheDocument();

  });
});
```

After executing the test I see only  console.log src/pages/profile-page/avatar.js:13   "Started" and never finished.

if I force onload to be completed :

```
beforeAll(()=> {
    global.Image = class {
      constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.onload(); // simulate success
        }, 100);
      }
    };
  });
```

height and width will be undefined every time.
So is there a trick to make image objects testable in jest/rtl?

Comment: [register-transfer-level] is almost certainly the wrong tag. Did you mean [react-testing-library]? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I think you should use [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani,  [findBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#findby-queries) methods are a combination of getBy queries and waitFor. Default timeout for findBy*** is 1000 ms.